# How to remove the link to the references in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I'm using LaTeX with `biblatex` (and `beamer`), and in the top left corner there's a link to the references. Does someone knows how to remove it? Thanks :)

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

And the minimal working code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Szeged}
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\bibliography{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        This is a random text\cite{Author:1}.
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \printbibliography{}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With the file sources.bib containing:

```
@ARTICLE{Author:1, 
author={Doe, John}, 
journal={Hello}, 
title={No idea}, 
year={2015}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In particular, please let us know which `beamer` themes you use.

Comment: I added the minimal code. Concerning the theme, I tried several but the issue seems to be independant of the chosen theme. And thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cause of that is that `beamer` places the names of `\section`s in the header. It is a form of navigation, the current section will be highlighted. `biblatex` automatically inserts at `\section` (or `\chapter`, depending on documentclass) at the start of the reference list. Hence, one way of removing that is to make `biblatex` *not* create a heading at all, which you can do with

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

(Note that the pair of braces you have after `\printbibliography` is unnecessary.)

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Szeged}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        This is a random text\cite{aksin}.
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \printbibliography[heading=none]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]